# How to write an immutable TallySet (counting multiset) in FSharp

Tags: f#, overriding, immutability, sealed

I am trying to create an immutable collection type that behaves  as a hybrid
of multiset/bag and Map that records the number of occurrences of each item.

I can write a mutable one with code a little like below and I tried to write an immutable one by inheriting from Map but Map is sealed and will not let me define any overrides.

```
type TallySet<'k_t when 'k_t : comparison>() = class
    //    inherit Map<'k_t, int>
    let m_map:((Map<'k_t, int>) ref) = ref (Map.empty)

    member x.add item =
        m_map :=
            match (!m_map).TryFind item with
                | None -> (!m_map).Add(item, 1)
                | Some n -> (!m_map).Add(item, 1 + n)
       !m_map

    member x.Count with get() = Map.fold (fun cc k v -> cc + v) 0 !m_map
end
```

What should I write ?

Comment: Looking at the code for the [Map type in F#](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/map.fs) and the [corresponding signature file](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/map.fsi) would be a good start. Note that most of the functions you'd use use day to day are in the map module, (scroll slightly down).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [ExtCore.Collections.Multiset](https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore/blob/master/ExtCore/Collections.Multiset.fs). As in your code, it's just a map with the value type set to the count. `Multiset.add` and `Multiset.count` correspond to the members in your example.